# Markov chain on $\mathcal{Z}$, hitting probability after having done negative jumps of total magnitude $k$

Tags: probability, markov-chains

I'm considering a random walk Y on $\mathbb{Z}$ with jump sizes in $[-E, E]$, defined as follow: $Y_0 = 0$ and for $n \ge 1 $:
$$Y_n = \sum_{i = 1}^n X_i,$$
with $(X_i)$ a family of i.i.d random variables.

I'm interested in computing the probability that $Y$ reaches a non negative state, given that the random walk has already made negative jumps of size $k$.

In other words, and let $Y_n^- = \sum_{i=0}^n \max(0, -X_i)$ be the process counting the total size of negative jumps and $Y_n^+ = \sum_{i=0}^n \max(0, X_i)$, so that $Y_n = Y_n^+ - Y_n^-$.

Let $\tau_k = \inf \{ n \ge 0 : Y_n^- \ge k \}$. I want to compute
$$p_k = \mathbb{P}(\exists n \ge \tau_k ; Y_n \ge 0 ).$$

When $E = 1$ (i.e. $\pm 1$ jumps), I can derive an analytical expression for this probability.

However, I'd like to derive an analytical expression for the probability, or at least an upper bound when the jumps are not restricted to $\pm 1$. In particular, I'm interested in the case where the direction of the jump is drawn from a Bernoulli distribution and the size of the jumps drawn from a Binomial distribution:
\begin{align}
\mathbb {P} (X=k) & = p {E \choose k}\,p^{k}(1-p)^{E - k} \\
\mathbb {P} (X=-k) & = (1 - p) {E \choose k}\, (1-p)^{k} p^{E - k}
\end{align}
when the random walk is biased towards negative jumps ($p < 0.5$).

---

An approach to solve this question would be to compute the probability distribution of $Y_\tau$, $P(Y_\tau)$. From there, it reduces to a standard hitting problem and one can compute the hitting probability (at least numerically) using standard tools for Markov chains.

Any hints on how to solve these kind of problems would be appreciated.

Comment: You say that the jump sizes are in $[-E,E]$, but then you say that $E=1$ corresponds to $\pm1$ jumps, not jumps in $[-1,1]$. Is there a typo somewhere?

Comment: @joriki what you ask doesn't constitute an error in and of itself...the random walk is on $\mathbb{Z}$, so from the outset the jumps are in $\mathbb{Z} \cap [-E,E]$.

Comment: But I am confused by the binomially distributed size of jumps. So if jump direction is positive, the jump size is $\mathrm{Bin}(E,p)$? Your formula for size $k$ then seems to include $n$ and somehow be for $(k-1)$?

Comment: There was a typo, $n$ was supposed to be $E$.
Also you are right, it was not a binomial distribution. My model is slightly different and I wanted to simplify as much as possible. I've modified the question so that it's now a binomial distribution.
I don't expect to find a simple solution. I'd rather know if there are usual methods to deal with these kind of questions.